# How to partially mock a class using Mockery?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mockery

I have this class:

```
class PagSeguro {

    public function pay()
    {
        if ( ! $this->checkAllData() )
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->buildPaymentURL();
    }

    private function checkAllData()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private function buildPaymentURL()
    {
        echo "not cool!\n\n";

        return true;
    }

}
```

And this test for it:

```
public function testPagSeguroPaymentData()
{
    $m = m::mock('PagSeguro[buildPaymentURL]');

    $m->shouldReceive('buildPaymentURL')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn('http://');

    $this->assertEquals($m->pay(), 'http://');
}
```

If I var_dump($m) I see the mocked method:

```
    'buildPaymentURL' =>
    class Mockery\ExpectationDirector#1507 (5) {
      protected $_name =>
      string(15) "buildPaymentURL"
      protected $_mock =>
              ...

      protected $_expectations =>
      array(1) {
        ...
      }
      protected $_expectedOrder =>
      NULL
      protected $_defaults =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

But when the test executes, it's calling not the mocked one but the real one. Unless I rename it

```
private function buildPaymentURL_RENAMED() {}
```

And then I get a green.

Anyone can show me the right way of doing those partial mocks using Mockery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you cannot have that method be `private`, because the very time you enter the code of your real object, any call to `$this->buildPaymentURL` MUST end up in that real private method.

Make it protected. That way, the mock can extend your class and overwrite the function.

On the other hand, I always have a bit of a bad feeling if there is a need for such partial mocks. They are most likely a sign of bad design. It seems that this private method should rather be contained in an object of its own that is dealing with URL creation exclusively (and can be tested seperately), and this class you are testing now should only get a complete mock of that new class injected.

Comment: Had to make it public for it work, as protected behaviour is the same. About design: the whole purpose of this class is actually this URL, there are other methods on it to put data together, but the 'payment' part is made by this method, wich calls an external library, wich talks with a payment service (PagSeguro). But thanks for your advice, there must be something wrong with it anyway. :)

Comment: Ok, if it calls an external lib, mock that lib!

Comment: Great. Will do it. Thanks again.